# Check value of array in array had same value

Tags: php

I had a loop which will give me array(array());From mysql join it gave 3 results, 2 result had same agency name so when i loop it display 2 agencies same name , so i want to check if same agency name , will output that agency name only one time.

```
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="selected_news" value="<?=$agency['aid'];?>" name="news_id[]"></td>
                  <td><?=$agency['aid']?></td>
                  <td><?=$agency['aname']?></td>
                  <td><?=date('d/m/Y',$agency['aid'])?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
$agencyIDs = array();

foreach($agencies as $agency)
{
    $agencyID = $agency['aid'];
    if(!in_array($agencyID, $agencyIDs))
    {
        ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="selected_news" value="<?= $agencyID; ?>" name="news_id[]"></td>
        <td><?= $agencyID ?></td>
        <td><?= $agency['aname'] ?></td>
        <td><?= date('d/m/Y', $agency['aid']) ?></td>
        <?php
        $agencyIDs[] = $agencyID;
    }
}
```